# Что значит "beef language" в меню?

Tags: переводы

Недавно был в ресторане на территории международного аэропорта в Грузии, в меню увидел следующую позицию - **beef language**. Заказать не осмелился. Все друзья надо мной посмеялись, сказали, чтобы я учил русский язык. Что значит это название?

Comment: А почему сказали, чтоб учил русский, если написано на английском?

Answer (score 4):

Не знаю, насколько этот вопрос подходит под формат сайта. Но отвечу.

Думаю, что это плохой перевод с русского "говяжий язык".
Хороший перевод был бы "beef tongue".

В русском эти два значения омонимичны, при переводе возникают подобные ляпы.

(+) =====

Только сейчас понял, что речь идет о Грузии. В грузинском, помнится, слова  tongue и language тоже омонимичны. Так что переводили скорее всего с грузинского.